# BTD Battles Mobile - Which tower activates the special ability

Tags: bloons-td-battles

In BTD Battles Mobile, when you have multiple towers with the same special ability purchased, which tower activates the special ability?

Edit: I figured I can test this in Practice mode (now that I found out how to make money in defense mode. And it appears the it goes by order of upgrading to Misdirection.

Comment: I believe any tower will activate that special ability. For instance, you can click on any Mage tower and activate the Phoenix however many times you have that fully upgraded tower.

Comment: That may be true for location independent abilities, but this ability works in the range of the tower, so it's quite important.

Answer (score 1):

Abilities will be activated by towers in the order in which you place them.